# no matching function for call to ‘Gtk::Main::run(window (&)())

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, parentheses

I guess I'm not understanding something about C++:

I have this code:

```
#include "window.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    window win();
    Gtk::Main::run(win);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

'window' is a class that inherits from Gtk::Window with an empty constructor.  When I try to compile this code, I get this error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Gtk::Main::run(window (&)())
```

However, if I change the line:

```
window win();
```

to

```
window win;
```

then the code compiles.  How do the presence/absence of the parentheses change things?  I've run into this before and never understood what was going on.  What's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `window win();` is the declaration of a function taking no parameters and returning a `window`. (Hence the error saying no matching call for `window (&)()`, which is that type.)

This is known as the "Most Vexing Parse."

Comment: Oh wow.  That's kind of odd coming from a Java/C# background.  Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: @Jrop: Yeah, bit of a dark corner. No problem.